# navigation wrapper for android using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm a web developer and I'm trying to develop android application (at this time) using phonegap because I need to complete an application quickly, I know css,javascript,HTML5 so I can utilize my current skills to develop an android application.

Many people are using jquery-mobile to use inside phonegap, but I don't want to use jquery mobile, I think jquery mobile is not for application development, it is developed for mobile web development. It is too heavy and with lot of dependancies.

I read some article, that we need to use an wrapper to acheieve the in-app navigations, He said "Like we have in native app development", I am not an native app developer of any platform, so I am not aware of any wrappers like this. How can I write a javascript Wrapper which manages the navigations inside the app.(not for passsing to server). I don't even have an idea where to start?

Navigation in websites done by links and opening different pages, how it can be done in native apps (or native look like apps).?

Any article or sample code will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is great for declaring static documents, but it falters when we try to use it for declaring dynamic views in web-applications. **AngularJS** lets you extend HTML vocabulary for your application. ***[More...](https://angularjs.org/)***

***[1) Tutorials](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00)***

***[2) AngularJS Transitions](http://angular-transitions.mgechev.com/#/view/page1)***
`